# Activerecord checking if association exist

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have two ActiveRecord models:

```
class Class < ActiveRecord::Base
    (...)
    has_many :class_to_teacher, dependent: :destroy
end

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :classes,
          through: :class_to_teacher
end

class ClassToTeacher < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :klass
     belongs_to :teacher
end
```

When I remove Class I don't remove it completly only I remove record from ClassToTeacher record. I need to keep this data:

```
def leave(class, teacher)
    teacher.klasses.delete(class)
end
```

Now I have to get all associated classes (classes which contains record in ClassToTeacher). How to do this the best? Thanks for all answers.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, to you want to retrieve all the classes (from Class) where the relation is not empty ? (All the classes that has at least one classs_to_teacher) ?

Comment: Yes I would like to have all classes where relation is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like that:

```
 Class.includes(:class_to_teacher).where('class_to_teacher.id is not null').references(:class_to_teacher).all
```

Assuming that you have an 'id' field in your database for the ClassToTeacher

Answer (score 0):

I guess there's a lot of ways to get there but the simplest one is probably this:

```
Klass.where(id: KlassToTeacher.select(:klass_id))
```

This will result in a single query with a sub-query. Note that I changed the names of the models because `Class` is already defined in Ruby and you're just asking for trouble.